# What is the Fully qualified file path when using google cloud shell file download in the browser

Tags: shell, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use the browser Google Cloud shell. There is a menu option within it to download a file. It asks the user to put in a Fully qualified file path.

I have tried many variations of file name and path but it keep failing without error.

If I have a path like this, and file 'test.txt':

root@some-long-unique-value:/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.customappurl.com

What do I enter?

I have tried:

- root@some-long-unique-value:/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.customappurl.com/test.txt
- some-long-unique-value:/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.customappurl.com/test.txt
- /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.customappurl.com/test.txt
- test.txt

At this time, I am just manually copying the text file. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your third option, /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.customappurl.com/test.txt, should work. I just verified it. Can you try 'cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.customappurl.com/test.txt' to make sure the file exists?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to test a file download in another directory and it worked. I will have to try this next time I need it. Do you think this download function could be effected by permission level? I had to sudo to root to access the letsencrypt directory, I figured maybe when I was elevated to root that the download feature would be too, but maybe that is not the case.